# Trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 on Macbook 2016 - getting black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook

New to Linux and I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a new Macbook 2016. Getting a black screen when I try any commands from the GRUB. I have edited the install Ubuntu line to contain nomodeset but when pressing F10 I still received a black screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)